# Problems using modal within non-modal window

Tags: kendo-ui

I am trying to use a modal window within another window as a confirm/message popup, but there are some issues I am not sure if I can't get around.

Here's a jsfiddle of my situation:  [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zholen/fTrXD/3/)

The problems I am trying to fix are:

1. Using a modal window while also using appendTo seems to have issues with the back drop, I see its there until you click elsewhere, then it disappears.
2. It would be great if I could center the modal within my window rather than the Window
3. Even though dragging is disabled on the modal, if you grab the modal title bar, it will move the outside window.
4. If I click the 'X' to close the inner modal, it closes my external window.

Can anyone suggest solutions to any of these issues?

```
$('<div id="confirmModal"><div id="confirmWindow">Is This Correct?<p><input type="button" id="btnYes" value="Yes" /><input type="button" id="btnNo" value="No" /></p></div></div>').prependTo('#Window');
$('#confirmWindow').kendoWindow({
  modal: true,
  resizable:false,
  draggable:false,
  appendTo: '#Window',
  close: function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
      $('#confirmWindow').kendoWindow('destroy');
    }, 200);
  }
});

$('#confirmWindow').find('#btnNo').click(function () {
    $('#confirmWindow').kendoWindow('close');
});
$('#confirmWindow').find('#btnYes').click(function () {
    $('#confirmWindow').kendoWindow('close');
});
```

**Edit**

I have edited the fiddle as the first one was an older version of what i meant to post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `appendTo` [documentation](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/window#configuration-appendTo):

> The element that the Window will be appended to. **Note that this does not constrain the window dragging within the given element**.

So, Kendo windows are floating, they are not constrained to the element that you append it to. This means that does not make sense `prepend` the confirmation window to an HTML element and then `append` it to that same element.

Comment: I do not see how this addresses any of the issues I listed above. I simply add the confirmwindow html to the page, then when i turn that into a kendo window, i say to appendTo that same container rather than being created at a higher level. I do not see how my use of prepend and then appendTo has anything to do with my question as they are related to two separate things.

Comment: Or perhaps what you are saying is that my intentions as a whole do not make sense? In which case saying such a thing is not an answer, it is simply a criticism and unhelpful.

Comment: It is not saying that what you are trying to achieve does not make sense, just the opposite: I did try it also! What I mean is that it does not make sense to Kendo UI code. My answer is that with KendoUI out-of-the-box _is not possible_. Of course, you can write a lot of code for getting it _but_ it is something not officially supported. I just wanted to emphasize that due to the fact that Kendo UI windows are floating, they are not constrained to where the HTML code is inserted. Do not take it as something personal or offensive. Sorry for the misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

Check response from a telerik enginer
http://www.kendoui.com/forums/kendo-ui-web/window/kendowindow-appendto-boundaries.aspx

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#windowName").data("kendoWindow").dragging._draggable.bind("drag", function (e) {

        var wnd = $("#window").data("kendoWindow");
        var position = wnd.wrapper.position();

        var minT = 0;
        var minL = 0;
        //Get the Window width and height and
        //place them in position of the hard-coded width and height
        var maxT = 600 - wnd.wrapper.height();
        var maxL = 900 - wnd.wrapper.width();

        if (position.left < minL) {
            coordinates = { left: minL };
            $(wnd.wrapper).css(coordinates);
        }

        if (position.top < minT) {
            coordinates = { top: minT };
            $(wnd.wrapper).css(coordinates);
        }

        if (position.left > maxL) {
            coordinates = { left: maxL };
            $(wnd.wrapper).css(coordinates);
        }

        if (position.top > maxT) {
            coordinates = { top: maxT };
            $(wnd.wrapper).css(coordinates);
        }
    })
})
</script>
```